# Django admin panel not showing related foreign key correctly - Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I'm new to Django. I've defined 2 tables and have set a foreign key. So I want to link the column **note** from table **Comment** to the column **id** from table **Note**.

As I'm using PostgreSQL, when I check the psql shell, the name of the column **note** will be displayed as **note_id**.

So for using in template, if I use something like `comment.note`, it prints the **"quick_note"** of the **note** table, which I don't want that. I want to get the **"id"** of the related post to the current comment, not the quick_note of the related post. But if I use something like `comments.note_id`, it shows the id of the related post, which is what I expect to get.

[image]

Also in the admin panel, I see a field of **note:** that shows related quick_note not id. How can I fix it that admin panel show the related id? So here I want the id of related post to be shown in front of **note:**.

[image]

This is my model.py:

```
class Note(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       quick_note = models.CharField(max_length=500)
       pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
       author = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Comment(models.Model):
      text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      note = models.ForeignKey(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behavior of Django, the foreignKey field points to an object while field_id maps to primary key of the object, this important in case of assignment as if you try to save

```
comment.note = 1
```

You will get an exception

If you try to save

```
comment.note_id  = note
```

You will get exception as well.

Regarding your admin question, the best solution is to set ‘raw_id_fields’, it will act as you desire and it will make your system faster in adding/editing objects.

```
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        raw_id_fields = ['note']

try:
        admin.site.unregister(Comment)
except: pass
admin.site.register(Comment,CommentAdmin)
```

Comment: Would you please give me a little sample code in my case? And I didn't get what does 'raw_id_fields' do exactly, so would you explain that a little more clear?

Comment: Thank yo so much. It helped.

Comment: Forgot to notice that (models.ModelAdmin), must change to (admin.ModelAdmin).

Comment: Good catch, sorry.